# how to form a new array based on part of an existing array

Tags: perl

I was trying to build a new array based on an existing array.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#join
use warnings;
use strict;

my @names = ('jacob', 'michael', 'joshua', 'mathew');
my @t_names = join ("\t" , @names);
my @t_names2 = join ("\t", $names[0],$names[2]);
print @t_names, "\n";
print @t_names2, "\n";
```

The test script allows me to join 2 elements from the old array to form a new array. But what if my array has 1000 elements and I would like to form a new array that contains only a selective portion of the 1000 elements (say, element 3 and 3 multiples). I tried `join ("\t", $names[0,2])` but perl doesn't recognize `$names[0,2]` (output suggests that `$names[0,2]` is "recognized" as `$names[2]`. And not sure what this error means "`multidimensional syntax not supported at join.pl`"

If `join` is not the right function, what other way could I build a partial array from an existing array? Thank you.

Comment: Just realized this example misrepresents my REAL problem with "join" function. But both answers have helped with another issue that I am struggling with. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Whenever you want more than one thing out of an array, whether it's all the items or some subset, you use `@` instead of `$`.

You can select any subset of items from an array with `@`*arrayname*`[`*list*`]`, where *list* is a list of indexes.  You can put a literal list of comma-separated index values, but you can also put any expression that returns a list. ysth's solution uses the expression `grep $_ % 3 == 0, 3..$#names`.   Breaking it down, that uses these elements:

- `$#names` to get the index of the last element in `@names`
- the range construct `..` to generate a list of all the numbers from 3 up to that value
- `grep` to extract from that list of numbers only the ones matching a condition
- that condition being the expression `$_ % 3 == 0`, which means "the remainder when the number is divided by 3 is 0", which of course is only true for multiples of 3

So if the array has 1000 elements, then `$#names` is 999, and `3..$#names` is a 997-element list containing the numbers (3,4,5,6,7,8,...) all the way up to 999.  Running `grep $_ % 3 == 0` on that list returns a 333-element list containing the numbers (3,6,9,12,...) all the way up to 999, and then asking for `@names[3,6,9,12,...,996,999]` returns the 333 elements located at those positions in the `@names` array.

Answer (score 11):

To get a slice of an array, use `@names[0,2]`, not `$names[0,2]`.

To get an explanation of an error message, `use diagnostics;`, which gives:

> Multidimensional syntax $names[0,2] not supported at ...
>
> (W syntax) Multidimensional arrays aren't written like $foo[1,2,3].
>      They're written like $foo[1][2][3], as in C.

which is perl noticing you are doing something wrong but being wrong about what you were trying to do :)

join creates a string, never a list, so presumably you want to just:

```
my @new_array = @names[ @indexes_to_select ];
```

To select only indexes from 3 on that are multiples of 3:

```
my @new_array = @names[ grep $_ % 3 == 0, 3..$#names ];
```